# Prove that $2^{k}+1 \mid 2^{k767}+1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Does $2^{k}+1 \mid 2^{k\cdot767}+1$,what are the necessary conditions.
At first look I can only find modular restrictions on $k$.
Any help?

Thank you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To say that $2^{k} + 1 \mid 2^{a k} + 1$ is equivalent to saying that $2^{a k} + 1 \equiv 0 \pmod{2^{k} + 1}$.

Now $2^{k} \equiv -1 \pmod{2^{k} + 1}$, so that
$$
2^{a k} + 1 \equiv (-1)^{a} + 1 \equiv \dots \pmod{2^{k} + 1}
$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Let $n$ be an odd integer and $ k\in {\mathbb N}$, $a, b \in {\mathbb R}$. Then
$$ a^{kn}+b^{kn}=(a^k)^n+(b^k)^n=(a^k+b^k)(a^{k(n-1)}-a^{k(n-2)}b^k+\cdots+b^{k(n-1)}). $$